# Is it expensive for z3 to solve a constraint set with quantifiers?

Tags: z3

I am using z3 (v4.3.1) to solve a constraint set containing uninterpreted functions with quantifiers. The problem is that the memory usage of z3 is very high. Below is my constraint:

```
(solver
(v0 0)
(forall ((i Int))
(let ((a!1 (=> (v0 i)
               (and (not (v1 i))
                    (not (v2 i))
                    (not (v3 i))
                    (not (v4 i))
                    (not (v5 i))))))
  (=> (>= i 0) a!1)))
(forall ((i Int)) (=> (>= i 0) (=> (v0 i) (v1 (+ i 1)))))
(forall ((i Int))
(let ((a!1 (=> (v1 i)
               (and (not (v0 i))
                    (not (v2 i))
                    (not (v3 i))
                    (not (v4 i))
                    (not (v5 i))))))
  (=> (>= i 0) a!1)))
forall ((i Int))
(let ((a!1 (=> (v1 i) (or (v2 (+ i 1)) (v5 (+ i 1))))))
  (=> (>= i 0) a!1)))
(forall ((i Int))
(let ((a!1 (=> (v2 i)
               (and (not (v0 i))
                    (not (v1 i))
                    (not (v3 i))
                    (not (v4 i))
                    (not (v5 i))))))
  (=> (>= i 0) a!1)))
(forall ((i Int)) (=> (>= i 0) (=> (v2 i) (v3 (+ i 1)))))
(forall ((i Int))
(let ((a!1 (=> (v3 i)
               (and (not (v0 i))
                    (not (v1 i))
                    (not (v2 i))
                    (not (v4 i))
                    (not (v5 i))))))
  (=> (>= i 0) a!1)))
(forall ((i Int)) (=> (>= i 0) (=> (v3 i) (v4 (+ i 1)))))
(forall ((i Int))
(let ((a!1 (=> (v4 i)
               (and (not (v0 i))
                    (not (v1 i))
                    (not (v2 i))
                    (not (v3 i))
                    (not (v5 i))))))
  (=> (>= i 0) a!1)))
(forall ((i Int)) (=> (>= i 0) (=> (v4 i) (v1 (+ i 1)))))
(forall ((i Int))
(let ((a!1 (=> (v5 i)
               (and (not (v0 i))
                    (not (v1 i))
                    (not (v2 i))
                    (not (v3 i))
                    (not (v4 i))))))
  (=> (>= i 0) a!1)))
(forall ((i Int)) (=> (>= i 0) (=> (v5 i) (v5 (+ i 1)))))
(exists ((i Int)) (=> (>= i 0) (v5 i)))
(forall ((i Int))
(let ((a!1 (not (v5 (- (+ i 3) 1)))))
(let ((a!2 (=> (and (v0 i) (v1 (+ i 1))) a!1)))
  (=> (>= i 0) a!2))))
(forall ((i Int))
(let ((a!1 (not (v5 (- (+ i 4) 1)))))
(let ((a!2 (=> (and (v3 i) (v4 (+ i 1)) (v1 (+ i 2))) a!1)))
```

When I write the constraint set into a smt2 file and use z3 to solve it, I get the result "unknow" quickly. Below is content of the smt2 file

```
(declare-fun v0 (Int) Bool)
(declare-fun v1 (Int) Bool)
(declare-fun v2 (Int) Bool)
(declare-fun v3 (Int) Bool)
(declare-fun v4 (Int) Bool)
(declare-fun v5 (Int) Bool)
(assert (v0 0))
(assert  (forall ((i Int)) (=> (v0 i)     (and (not (v1 i)) (not (v2 i)) (not (v3 i))    (not (v4 i)) (not (v5 i))))))
(assert  (forall ((i Int)) (=> (v1 i)     (and (not (v0 i)) (not (v2 i)) (not (v3 i))   (not (v4 i)) (not (v5 i))))))
assert  (forall ((i Int)) (=> (v2 i)     (and (not (v1 i)) (not (v0 i)) (not (v3 i)) (not (v4 i)) (not (v5 i))))))
(assert  (forall ((i Int)) (=> (v3 i)     (and (not (v1 i)) (not (v2 i)) (not (v0 i)) (not (v4 i)) (not (v5 i))))))
(assert  (forall ((i Int)) (=> (v4 i)     (and (not (v1 i)) (not (v2 i)) (not (v3 i)) (not (v0 i)) (not (v5 i))))))
(assert  (forall ((i Int)) (=> (v5 i)     (and (not (v1 i)) (not (v2 i)) (not (v3 i)) (not (v4 i)) (not (v0 i))))))
(assert  (forall ((i Int)) (=> (>= i 0) (=> (v0 i) (v1 (+ i 1))))))
(assert  (forall ((i Int)) (=> (>= i 0) (=> (v1 i) (or (v2 (+ i 1)) (v5 (+ i 1)))))))
(assert  (forall ((i Int)) (=> (>= i 0) (=> (v2 i) (v3 (+ i 1))))))
(assert  (forall ((i Int)) (=> (>= i 0) (=> (v3 i) (v4 (+ i 1))))))
(assert  (forall ((i Int)) (=> (>= i 0) (=> (v4 i) (v1 (+ i 1))))))
(assert  (forall ((i Int)) (=> (>= i 0) (=> (v5 i) (v5 (+ i 1))))))
(assert  (exists ((i Int)) (=> (>= i 0) (v5 i))))
(assert (forall ((i Int)) (=> (>= i 0) (=> (and (v0 i) (v1 (+ i 1))) (not (v5 (+ i 2)))))))
(assert (forall ((i Int)) (=> (>= i 0) (=> (and (v3 i) (v4 (+ i 1)) (v1 (+ i 2))) (not (v5 (+ i 3)))))))
(check-sat)
```

I just wonder whether I write something wrong or the problem is hard for z3 to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Only the last assert causes the problem, if you remove it from your code then you obtain "sat"

Comment: But, the last assert must be added and indeed this constraint set is unsat.

Comment: If you  remove only the first assert keeping at his place the last assert you obtain "sat" again.